# Can I expect my application's constructor to get executed completely before my service methods are invoked?

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-service-binding, android-application-class

Coming straight to question,

1. App_A -> binds with service in App_B
2. App_B tries to init few values in it's application class constructor

Can I expect App_B's Application class constructor to get executed completely before the service methods (constructor (or) onStart (or) onBind) within App_B starts getting executed?

Comment: That depends on how you define "completely". If the constructor kicks off work in background threads, then those threads may still be going. But the constructor itself should complete before the service gets instantiated and called.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I'm not forking any new thread :-) So in that case i can expect it to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's true. The app will block until it finishes instantiating the Application class. So if you are doing a **blocking** operation in the Application's constructor or on the `onCreate` method, it will be executed before anything else inside your application. Just make sure that these operations are executed in the main thread and not in a background thread!